# Why is Encoding.Convert needed when converting bytes in one encoding to a string in a different Encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

The following code shows how to convert bytes in one encoding to a string in a different encoding:

```
   byte[] utf8Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file)
   Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8
   Encoding iso88591 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
   byte[] iso88591Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso88591, utf8Bytes)
   string iso88591Text = iso88591.GetString(iso88591Bytes)
```

I don't see why the statement `Encoding.Convert` is needed in the conversion from bytes in one encoding to a string in a different encoding when a byte is a byte whatever the encoding. I mean why can't the UTF8 bytes be decoded directly into an ISO-8859-1 string instead of using the intermediate `Encoding.Convert` that converts the entire byte array from one encoding to another? Like this:

```
  byte[] utf8Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file)
  Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8
  Encoding iso88591 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
  string iso88591Text = iso88591.GetString(utf8bytes)
```

May be I'm missing something, is the point of `Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso88591, utf8Bytes)` to tell `Encoding.GetString` to interpret its result bytes as a single byte per character instead of multibytes per character? I guess I don't see how a byte array can be converted from one encoding to another since the elements of the byte array are not modified (i.e. the length of the converted byte array does not change).

Comment: I think you're confused. C# strings are UTF-16, always. There's no such thing as an ISO-8859-1 string in C#, just UTF-16 strings and byte arrays representing strings in various encodings. Why are you trying to use ISO-8859-1 at all? Why aren't you going from a byte array containing UTF-8 bytes to a C# string?

Comment: bytes are _bytes_, just a collection of 8 bits. nothing more. they don't know if they are ascii, utf8, utf32, part of a floating point number, or just part of a random bitstream. there's no such thing as "UTF8 bytes". there's just bytes. the converter needs that information to _know_ that those bytes have to be interpreted as UTF8, and to produce an output that's interpreted as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Encoding.Convert changes a byte array representing a string in one encoding, to a byte array representing the same string in a different encoding. Actual strings aren't involved

Comment: String are two bytes where some characters are one byte characters and others two byte characters.  8 bit encoding was inverted to use only one byte for every character to save space.  So for all encoding the characters 0x00 to 0x7F are the same.  Each encoding type maps the one byte character 0x80 to 0xFF to a two byte unicode character.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann "he converter needs that information to know that those bytes have to be interpreted as UTF8,", what information are you referring to?

Comment: @canton7 I think I understand now, thanks. So the bytes in the byte array can change? Am I right in thinking that `Encoding.Convert` is needed so that when you call `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes)` each byte in bytes is mapped to the correct (i.e. corresponding) ISO-8859-1 character?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia They're not changing, you're creating a new byte array with different bytes in, which represent the same characters but in a different encoding. I've no idea why you think that `Encoding.Convert` is needed: if the aim is to get a string from a UTF-8 byte array, then use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and forget all about ISO-8859-1

Comment: @canton7 oh yeah, I forgot a new byte array is created and returned, thanks for pointing that out. And I've confirmed through testing that I don't need to use `Encoding.Convert` since `Encoding.Convert` applies the source encoding to the byte array. Since I want an ISO-8859-1 string I can just use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes)` to get a string from a byte array that maps to an ISO-8859-1 string.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Yet again, there is **no such thing as an ISO-8859-1 string in C#**. Again, **C#'s strings are ALWAYS UTF-16** (but you should never need to worry about that. You can have **byte arrays** which represent strings in different encodings, but strings themselves only ever come in one flavour. You're confused about what you want. Converting a UTF-8 byte array to an ISO-8859-1 byte array, then converting that to a string, **is pointless and dangerous**. If you want a string, turn your UTF-8 byte array into a string directly, as I said before.

Comment: We still can't answer your question, because you refuse to articulate what your problem actually is...

Comment: @canton7 I missed your first reply. I'm using ISO-8859-1 because I'm reading a binary file that has a file encoding of latin-1 into C#, processing the contents in C# and writing the modified content out to a new file that retains the latin-1 file encoding.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia So if the file is encoded in ISO-8859-1, why are you trying to turn the bytes in that file from UTF-8 into ISO-8859-1? Where did UTF-8 come from? If you just want to turn bytes which represent ISO-8859-1 into a C# string, use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(file))`. Again, any use of `Encoding.Convert` anywhere here indicates a lack of understanding

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia the information, if those bytes are to be interpreted as an UTF8-string, a UTF16-string, a UTF32-string, an ASCII-string, [...]

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Please try and avoid confusing them -- I've been trying to make it clear that there's no such thing as a "UTF-8 string" in C# (since I think they believe that C# strings have an underlying encoding which isn't fixed at UTF-16), only bytes which, if you apply a UTF-8 encoding, turn into a C# string.

Comment: @canton7 thanks a lot, that's what I ended up doing after experimenting. As for where UTF-8 came from, I guess I thought that the byte array returned by `File.ReadAllBytes` had a UTF-8 encoding since I wrongly thought that UTF-8 was one byte per character (I thought the 8 meant 8 bits). So I figured `File.ReadAllBytes` returning a byte array meant that the byte array had the encoding UTF-8 which (I wrongly thought) used one byte per character. But now I know that bytes don't have an encoding, thanks to Franz Gleichmann.

Comment: Cool, glad it's clear in your mind. This would have been a lot easier if you'd explained that your file was encoded in ISO-8859-1 and you just wanted a C# string at the start of all of this!

Comment: @canton7 Yeah, I'll take that onboard, I'm still learning :). About the whole C# only has UTF-16 strings discussion, I know that string literals in C Sharp are UTF-16 strings, but surely if you run Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) the returned string is UTF-8 not UTF-16?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia No. Strings in C# are UTF-16, always. When you do `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`, that takes each byte (or set of bytes, since UTF-8 can use multiple bytes to encode a single character), from the UTF-8 encoded byte array and turns it into two bytes representing a single UTF-16 character, which becomes part of the C# string (or 4 UTF-16 bytes, for surrogate pairs)

Comment: @canton7 do you mean `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` turns each byte (or set of bytes) from the byte array into two bytes representing a single UTF-16 character, and the sequence of 2 bytes is how you get a UTF-16 string? Therefore, this insinuates that the UTF8 in `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` is for the byte array passed as an input, not for the output (i.e. not for the return value), is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218693/discussion-between-canton7-and-mywrathacademia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the string `Tèst`.

Its UTF-8 representation is (hex):

```
54 C3 A8 73 74
T    è   s  t
```

And its ISO-8859-1 is (hex):

```
54 E8 73 74
T  è  s  t
```

You can notice the difference between how `è` is represented.

So we know that every encoding can use different byte(s) to represent a certain character.

So if you have the bytes `C3 A8` you know that they represent the char `è` only because you know that it is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: I think I see what I'm missing now. Does `Encoding.Convert` change the bytes in UTF8 to their equivalent value in ISO-8859-1 (i.e. as @Cantor said "Encoding.Convert changes a byte array representing a string in one encoding, to a byte array representing the same string in a different encoding. Actual strings aren't involved"), so that iso8859.GetString() maps each byte to the right character? Just like in your example.